# htaccess rule is true but site gives 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm struggling to see why this rule won't work on the site.

The old url was /mobile/article/site/article-name and the new url is just /article/article-name

The rule is

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/article/tgc/(.*)$            /article/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Testing against http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with the whole htaccess file tells us

```
This rule was met, the new url is http://site.dev/article/article-name
Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

but when we try hit http://site.dev/mobile/article/site/article-name in the browser, we get a 404 rather than a redirect.

What's even more curious is that we have the same kind of rule for another url

```
RewriteRule ^resources/a/(.*)$                    http://resources.site.dev/library/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which comes after our troubled redirect and it works just peachy.

What are we missing?

Comment: Does your htaccess really say `^RewriteRule`? The `^` is way off there and would cause a syntax error, causing the rule not being processed.

Comment: What if you remove `^` before `RewriteRule` (don't know if it's a type error or whatever) and add `[R=301,L]` after `/article/$1` ? Also, do you have other rules ? If you're using some framework, put your rule before framework's main rule

Comment: yeah, the site is running on ExpressionEngine and all of these rules we have before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rule as this:

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/article/site/(.*)$ /article/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: yip, that's what we have, minus the NC but still 404

Comment: Make sure this is your very first rule and you don't have any other .htaccess in `/mobile/` folder or any other folder below that.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted because someone had added a ```/mobile/``` directory to the project with its own htaccess file.

Comment: Turns out the mobile directory is actually a sub domain which is no longer in use and its htaccess was to divert to the new site. Any ideas on how to solve that issue?

Comment: You can solve it by placing this rule in mobile directory's htaccess. Just remember to take `mobile/` out from URI pattern in your RewriteRule.